# Swift- how to retrieve messages in frequency from web service?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am trying to develope chat app. I have done created my web service with php and mysql.
The respond of web service is json format.

In swift part; i post some paramaters to web address and retrieve json respond then show the messages. I used use nstimer to post and retrieve the respond of my json respond. And if there is new message the show it.

I dont want to use nstimer for retrieve the message. Is there any better way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a REST-ful service, periodically polling is pretty much the standard way to do it.

Instead of polling, you could consider using a real-time update mechanism to either deliver the message, or else inform your client that you need to sync with the server. Google has developed a pretty robust, cross-platform solution that allows you to achieve this using the Push Notification protocol:

[Google GCM XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://blog.process-one.net/building-an-xmpp-ios-client-in-swift-2/). It uses XMPP to pass messages back and forward.

But if you want to do it yourself just to learn you have two options:

1. Use a restful api where you `GET` and `POST`. The timer you have isn't bad. I would recommend changing the time when the app is in the background or not doing it at all. You can use something like [parse](http://parse.com) to send PUSH notifications and reinitiate the `GET` calls when the user relaunches the app.
2. You could use WebSockets. WebSockets work a lot like BSD sockets except that they are wrapped in a HTTP(S) tunnel. With web sockets, you can check to see if the client you are looking for is connected. If they are, you just send them the message. If they are not, you do something like in option one using parse to send them a notification.

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**

Since parse is shutting down, you can use another service like it. I've never used [kinvey](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios) but it seems that they also provide similar services as parse like the [push notification](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/push) mentioned above

Comment: Parse would be a good suggestion, but they just announced they are closing down: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Oh. I didn't know. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Up vote but not selected correct answer. I want to see another helpful thoughts as yours. Thank you for ur ideas...